# Can you add data with int,double or just string to a JTable

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtable

I am new to Java. I mainly do C#. I was looking at the example on the link below:

[A Simple JTable Example for Display](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/a-simple-jtable-example-for-display)

But It gives me an error when creating a 2d Array that contains a int, a double a boolen, and a string. The error says "Type mismatch cannot convert from int to object". Does that means that the way this example shows is not right ? Im using Eclipse Juno. Any help would be appreciated

This is the code:
TableExample.java

```
package net.codejava.swing;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TableExample extends JFrame 
{
public TableExample()
{
    //headers for the table
    String[] columns = new String[] {
        "Id", "Name", "Hourly Rate", "Part Time"
    };

    //actual data for the table in a 2d array
    Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
        {1, "John", 40.0, false },
        {2, "Rambo", 70.0, false },
        {3, "Zorro", 60.0, true },
    };

    //create table with data
    JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);

    //add the table to the frame
    this.add(new JScrollPane(table));

    this.setTitle("Table Example");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new TableExample();
        }
    });
}   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you check the version of java that you are running? I am running version 7 and the code compiled fine for me. I am also able to see the output. In java version prior to version 5 the auto boxing of primitive data types like int, float to classes Integer, Float respectively, need to be done the user himself. You could try to redeclare/redefine data in the following way and run your program again:-

```
Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
    {new Integer(1), new String("John"), new Float(40.0), new Boolean(false) },
    {new Integer(2), new String("Rambo"), new Float(70.0), new Boolean(false) },
    {new Integer(3), new String("Zorro"), new Float(60.0), new Boolean(true) },
};
```

Comment: I have installed jdk1.8.0_05 that means java 8 ?

Comment: If i copied your answer and it worked ! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes looks like java 8. Can you give a try with the suggested code snippet?